# Installed Rails but not able to run it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm using `asdf` as a ruby package manager, I had a bunch of issues with the PATH environments and was able to install everything correctly. However, I'm running into issues with the rails gem.

I think I might still have ownership errors with it.

[image: Rails installation]

This is my path:

`/Users/carlos.grijalva/.asdf/shims:/Users/carlos.grijalva/.asdf/bin:/Users/carlos.grijalva/.rbenv/bin:/Users/carlos.grijalva/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

This is `which ruby`:

`/Users/carlos.grijalva/.asdf/shims/ruby`

And this is `ruby -v`:

`ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-darwin18]`

And this is my `GEM environment`

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.3 (2018-10-18 patchlevel 105) [x86_64-darwin18]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/carlos.grijalva/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/carlos.grijalva/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/carlos.grijalva/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/carlos.grijalva/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/carlos.grijalva/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/carlos.grijalva/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-18
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/carlos.grijalva/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
     - /Users/carlos.grijalva/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/carlos.grijalva/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/bin
     -
     - /Users/carlos.grijalva/.asdf/shims
     - /Users/carlos.grijalva/.asdf/bin
     - /Users/carlos.grijalva/.rbenv/bin
     - /Users/carlos.grijalva/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
```

Comment: Run `source ~/.zshrc` or `source ~/.bashrc` depending on your system

Answer (score 0):

You only want to use one ruby version manager.  Make sure you remove anything related to RBEN if you're not using it as your version manager.

Have a [look here](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/148) for things you may need to do.

You should also check your shell for any PATH definitions you don't need regarding RBENV.